# Monotouch dialog element like Wifi settings

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, xamarin

I am wondering if [Monotouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) has an `Element` like the one in iOS's settings for WiFi connections.  You can click it to select it (shows checkmark) and you click on the right arrow to edit the entry.

I am sure I can build it by hand, but want to make sure there isn't an element that already does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `StringElement` which you can use to display the right arrow. And there is a `CheckboxElement` that is selectable, but shows the checkmark on the right.

**There is no element that does both out of the box.**

I was personally looking for a checkbox and ended up creating one by hand, based on the `GlassButton` from `MT.D`.